# How to make text align under a box created in CSS

Tags: html, css, web, responsive-design

I was coding recently to learn more about html and CSS. I did not use any javascript as of now.

Right now, I am having a problem, since I am following a psd file, I need to make it into a html. I need to make a grey box and under that box, right in the middle underneath, I need to have a subheading and a paragraph, < p> < h4 >. See the picture below.

[image]

```css
.boxes{ 
  width: 500px; 
       background-color: #e6e6e6; 
    display: block;
    height: 130px;
    width: 230px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: .10em; 
    margin: 2em;
    border: double #fff 20px; 
    border-bottom: none; 
} 

.non-icons { 
    margin: 15%;   
}

.box_text{ 
 color: #8c8b8b;

}
```

```html
<div class="container"> 
    <div class="four columns">
        <div class="boxes"> 
            <i class="fa fa-desktop fa-4x non-icons"></i> 
        </div>
     <h4 class="box_text"> Web Design</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="four columns">
        <div class="boxes"> 
            <i class="fa fa-shopping-basket fa-4x non-icons"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="four columns">
        <div class="boxes"> 
            <i class="fa fa-signal fa-4x non-icons"></i>
        </div>
    </div>   
</div> <!-- End of Container -->
```

This looks fine in normal view, but it breaks when the screen narrows.

Please Help..

Thanks,
Devansh

Answer (score 0):

What you want to design is called a `grid`. Making grids that resize automatically for different screen sizes is what [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com) was invented for.

This w3schools example will help you (the Add Pricing Container example):

http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_theme_company.asp#myCarousel2

Also, read this part about how the grid system works.

http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp

Answer (score 0):

Grids work well for making layouts responsive. Or try putting your values in percentages(%) instead of definite units such as pixels or ems. This will make your layout much more fluid.

Bootstraps grid system is good.

Flexbox is also a good alternative. http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

You also have 2 `width` properties for `.boxes` which is confusing things.

Answer (score 0):

Of coarse if you aren't good with bootstrap you could 'jerry rig' in a way:

```
div{
    width:30%;
    overflow:hidden;
    height:250px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Then you put the elements in the div's and it will line up. Of coarse you can change the width and height. Make sure that the images are the same size/zoom and have the same padding/margin so it looks nice and uniform.

Also, you should consider reading an article on why PSD to HTML conversion is dying.

Comment: Hi..      I am actually using a grid called skeleton.css